# How to call a function after an async in Typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

Is there a way to call a function directly after an async() in Typescript? I currently have the following logic:

```
   const callNextAnimal = async () => {
        animal = animalFinder.getNextAnimal()
        playerSlideshow.showNextAnimal(animal)
      };
```

I want to now call a method that adds a counter after the async function is done

```
animalSlideshowInstance.addCounterFor(animal)
```

What I'm currently doing right now is saving the previous animal in my animalSlideShow class, then calling the counter. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
  const callNextAnimal = async () => {
        animalSlideshow.addCounterForPrevAnimal();
        animal = animalFinder.getNextAnimal()
        animalSlideshowInstance.setNewPreviousAnimal(animal);
        playerSlideshow.showNextAnimal(animal)
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the `await` keyword.

In fact, you only need to declare a function as `async` if you plan to use the `await` keyword inside it.